# Not able to use TinyMCE 4.7.9 in IE11

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using `TinyMCE 4.7.9` and it runs perfectly in `Chrome` and `Firefox.` But in `IE 11` (Version 11.0.9600) there is an error in the console.

```
TinyMCE does not support the browser you are using. For a list of supported browsers please see: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/system-requirements
```

In the system-requirements from `TinyMCE` the `IE 11` seems to be supported.

Anyone with the same Problem or a solution?

Comment: The system-requirements pages you link talks about “TinyMCE version 4.6.0”. Maybe they stopped support for IE11 with the 4.7.0…  
It seems that you should ask this question to TinyMCE devs, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you emulating an older IE release?  If you have IE11 set to emulate an older release you will see this message.

Comment: Yeah Thanks! I Emulated the IE 10 Document Mode. Editable in Developer Tools. Changed it to "Edge" and now its fine.

Answer (score 0):

You may have compatibility mode enabled. This could make TinyMCE think that you're using an older version of IE.